# Why doesn't Dart's DateTime object make use of the less than and greater than operator override methods?

Tags: datetime, dart, meta

So I've noticed that one of Dart's unique abilities that it has over other languages is that you can override "primitive" comparisons (`<, >, <=, >=, ==`) in order to implement your own methods.

Now I was also looking through the DateTime class documentation to understand what it is and how to use it, and I noticed that they've opted to have the named methods `DateTime.isBefore(DateTime other)` and `DateTime.isAfter(DateTime other)`. In human/pseudo code, these would translate to `dateTime < other` and `dateTime > other`, and naturally I thought why not just implement this directly into Dart?

I know this can be done using extensions as in [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/91371b77d07f38a271ef70ec1eefa353), and sure enough it works exactly as expected and to my knowledge, there's no way to know that an extension is being used...

*But why wasn't overriding operators considered when developing the `DateTime` object? Or if it was considered, why wasn't it included?*

Comment: Found this which seems to explain the issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/15693#issuecomment-108407898

Comment: Interesting. So it looks like that it wasn't included because consistency wouldn't have been able to be maintained... Kind of intriguing.

Comment: At this point you can use the dart_date library, which includes these operators. It's up to you to decide if lrn's warnings are relevant in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For several reasons, but mainly because the ordering is *not compatible with `==`*.

Two `DateTime` objects are equal if they have the same time *and* timezone, but they are considered before/after each other based entirely on the time, as modified for timezone.

It was considered a bad design to have `a <= b` which was not the same as (`a < b || a == b`), and for that reason, `<` and `<=` was dropped entirely.

Comment: Interesting. So if `a < b` is *apparently* determined entirely on the time (excluding timezone), excuse the naive question, but why not modify a/the spec to *include* the timezone in the comparison? After all, if a DateTime can be represented as an integer (adjusted to GMT time) it then makes it available to be compared with other GMT DateTime integers?

Comment: There is no `a<b` either, for the same reason. If it had existed, it should be compatible with `==`, but that does not  define a total ordering. Is 00:00:00Z before or after 01:00:00+01:00? They are not *equal* because of different time zones, but they are the same point in time. That's why it would not be a good idea to have a `<`, because you can have a,b where none of `a<b`, `b<a` or `a==b` holds.